# Nuke command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've made a nuke command in my discord bot, but I have 2 problems with it. First is how can i send a message to just created channel, and second is how can I make channel in same position as "original".

Here's my code:

```
# nuke
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue,
        title=f":boom: Channel ({ctx.channel.name}) has been nuked :boom:",
        description=f"Nuked by: {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}"
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild.name}  •  {datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.%Y at %I:%M %p')}")
    await ctx.channel.delete(reason="nuke")
    await ctx.channel.clone(reason="nuke")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the cloned channel in a variable:

```py
# nuke
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue,
        title=f":boom: Channel ({ctx.channel.name}) has been nuked :boom:",
        description=f"Nuked by: {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}"
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild.name}  •  {datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.%Y at %I:%M %p')}")
    await ctx.channel.delete(reason="nuke")
    channel = await ctx.channel.clone(reason="nuke")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The channel should be created in the same position as the original one, if not:

```py
pos = ctx.channel.position
await ctx.channel.delete()
channel = await ctx.channel.clone()
await channel.edit(position=pos)
```

Comment: dzięki, miłego dnia :))

Comment: dzięki, nawzajem :D